# Conditional explode in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I have data as below

```
+----------+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|athl_id   |Interest                           |branch                                                               |
+----------+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|123       |Running                            |Running,Outdoor                                                      |
|856       |Running                            |Running                                                              |
|902       |Training,Fitness                   |Fitness,Training                                                     |
|9567      |Swimming,Training,Fitness          |Swimming,Training,Fitness                                            |
|477       |All                                |Running,All,Training,Soccer,Swimming,Fitness,Outdoor,Indoor          |
|490       |Running,Indoor                     |Running,Indoor                                                       |
+----------+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now I want to explode two fields Interest and branch with below conditions.

1. For every athl_id, explode Interest field completely
2. If any of the comma separated values of branch equals to any of the comma separated values of Interest then ignore that value alone completely from branch and explode rest.
3. If no comma separated values of branch equals to any of the comma separated values of Interest then explode the field branch.

Ex - In the above table, athl_id - 902 has Interest in Training,Fitness  and since branch values are also same (Fitness,Training) they expected result has nulls for branch and Interest exploded to two rows.
Similarly, athl_id - 477 has Interest in All and branch has value  "Running,All,Training,Soccer,Swimming,Fitness,Outdoor,Indoor" but, since "All" is part of Interest, in result the filed branch which is exploded does not contain "All" but the rest "Running,Training,Soccer,Swimming,Fitness,Outdoor,Indoor"

**Expected result:**

```
+----------+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|athl_id   |Interest                           |branch                                                               |
+----------+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|123       |Running                            |Outdoor                                                              |
|856       |Running                            |                                                                     |
|902       |Training                           |                                                                     |
|902       |Fitness                            |                                                                     |
|9567      |Swimming                           |                                                                     |
|9567      |Training                           |                                                                     |
|9567      |Fitness                            |                                                                     |
|477       |All                                |Running                                                              |
|477       |All                                |Training                                                             |
|477       |All                                |Soccer                                                               |
|477       |All                                |Swimming                                                             |
|477       |All                                |Fitness                                                              |
|477       |All                                |Outdoor                                                              |
|477       |All                                |Indoor                                                               |
|490       |Running                            |                                                                     |
|490       |Indoor                             |                                                                     |
+----------+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now, I have tried something as below but, struck with an error. And also, I think "array_contains" isn't matching the exact values..

```
spark.sql("""  
select athl_id, Interest,
case when array_contains(split(branch,','),Interest) then null
else explode(split(branch,',')) end as branch
from (
select athl_id, explode(split(Interest,',')) as   Interest ,branch from athl_details)a
""").show(100,False )


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 767, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"Generators are not supported when it's nested in expressions
```

Can someone suggest me the right approach.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`array_except`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_except) function from Spark version >= 2.4.

Get the elements difference from the 2 columns after `split`ting them and use `explode_outer` on that column.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,explode_outer,array_except,split

split_col_df = df.withColumn('interest_array',split(col('interest'),',')) \
                 .withColumn('branch_array',split(col('branch'),','))
#Get the elements in branch not in interest
tmp_df = split_col_df.withColumn('elem_diff',array_except(col('branch_array'),col('interest_array')))
res = tmp_df.withColumn('interest_expl',explode_outer(col('interest_array'))) \
            .withColumn('branch_expl',explode_outer(col('elem_diff')))

res.select('athl_id','interest_expl','branch_expl').show()
```

If there can be duplicates in `branch` column and you only want to subtract equal number of occurrences of a common value, you might have to write a UDF to solve the problem.